# What is integral of a scalar field with respect to a variable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was reading Tom Apostol calculus volume 2 and came across theorem 10.8 (page 350)

> The theorem is:[image]

My doubt is, What is the definition of the right hand side of the underlined equation that is, What is the definition of $$\int_{a}^b \psi(\vec x,t)dt $$, this integral formally? I know integral of real valued function formally to some extent? **But what is the FORMAL DEFINITION OF THIS INTEGRAL**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused because $\psi(\vec{x},\,t)$ depends on multiple variables. But for each value of $\vec{x}$, $\psi(\vec{x},\,t)$ becomes just a function of $t$; you know how to integrate that. This recipe gives each $\varphi(\vec{x})$, thus defining the function $\varphi$.

Comment: I had thought of that about defining a different function g for each $\vec x$, as a function of only t, then integrating g. But then **how would you explain the next equation** that is taking the partial derivative of $\phi(\vec x)$ ?

Comment: @BijayanRag You have s function of $\vec{x}$; differentiate it.

Comment: your statement about function g (as per my last comment) is :-     for all $\vec x$ there exist a function  g such that $\psi 
(\vec x,t)$=g(t)

Comment: can you please tell me in formal words where are you getting a function of $\vec x$ to differentiate?

Comment: I think what I want to tell from the comments above is similar to the logical difference between uniform convergence and pointwise convergence & and also similar to logic behind existence of all directional derivative does not imply continuity

Comment: okay okay now it seems your are absolutely correct regarding the iintegral

Comment: But i still have a doubt, Can you please, Explain me in formal words which function, of $\vec x $ are you saying to differentiate?

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: though i am not quite sure till now about my understanding

Comment: so i may appreciate any other help too